# How to implement websocket++ ping handler?

Tags: c++, websocket, handler, ping, websocket++

I'm trying to detect lost connections that closed without sending the close frame by sending pings on a websocket++ application.

I'm having trouble setting up the handler.

I initially tried to set it up like how the handlers are setup with the [broadcast_server example](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp):

```
m_server.set_ping_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_m_server_ping,this,::_1,::_2));
```

That gives this error:

> note: candidate is:
>
> websocketpp/endpoint.hpp:240:10: note: void websocketpp::endpoint::set_ping_handler(websocketpp::ping_handler) [with connection = websocketpp::connection; config = websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client; websocketpp::ping_handler = std::function, std::basic_string)>]
>
> void set_ping_handler(ping_handler h) {

I thought that setting up a `typedef` like with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23023317/1382306) would solve it, but putting it outside the `class broadcast_server` makes it impossible to access `m_server`.

How can this handler be properly implemented?

### Includes & flags

Boost 1.54

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/common/thread.hpp>
typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio_tls> server;
```

**flags**

```
-std=c++0x -I ~/broadcast_server -D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_ 
 -D_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_CPP11_REGEX_ -lboost_regex -lboost_system 
 -lssl -lcrypto -pthread -lboost_thread
```

### `typedef`

```
typedef websocketpp::lib::function<bool(connection_hdl,std::string)> ping_handler;
```

Comment: Do you use standalone asio and C++11 or boost::asio? There is a difference how the boost::bind and std::bind works. If you precise the version of used packages and boost vs std case - I think I could answer that question.

Comment: @Tanuki Thank you Tanuki!  I've edited hopefully with the details you requested.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Could you replace flag -std=c++0x to -std=c++11 and see what happens then? I hope you GCC is higher than 4.7.3 (the first good one to support C++ 2011 standard)

Comment: @Tanuki  Thank you Tanuki!  Tried every combination for `bind`, still nothing.  As a side note, aren't those flags the same?  Thank you again so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Just updated from the git and building websocketpp for the boost. Give me some time.

Comment: @Tanuki Wow!  Thanks!  Let me know if you need me to give you more code.  I'm using TLS.

Comment: Can you put somewhere the code you trying to build? Websocket built good for me with all the examples and test. Put in somewhere in pastebin? I want to try to build your code. Im using gcc (Gentoo 4.8.3 p1.1, pie-0.5.9) 4.8.3/Boost 1.55.0-r1/Websocket++ 0.3.0.
Also, when I built the Websocket++ for myself - I changed -std=c++0x to -std=c++11.

Comment: @Tanuki The ping handler works for you?

Comment: There is no such handler in my examples. At least there is no such a thing inside broadcast_server.cpp.

Comment: @Tanuki It's a bit deeper in https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/e203dbed45409111c2e95cb3e4a1d178ee57d2bc/websocketpp/connection.hpp

Comment: Solved. See the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solving quite easy. First, the definition in websocket/connection.hpp:

```
/// The type and function signature of a ping handler
/**
 * The ping handler is called when the connection receives a WebSocket ping
 * control frame. The string argument contains the ping payload. The payload is
 * a binary string up to 126 bytes in length. The ping handler returns a bool,
 * true if a pong response should be sent, false if the pong response should be
 * suppressed.
 */
typedef lib::function<bool(connection_hdl,std::string)> ping_handler;
```

gives the basic idea that function must have the definition:

```
bool on_ping(connection_hdl hdl, std::string s)
{
  /* Do something */
  return true;
}
```

Now everything comes to the right place:

```
m_server.set_ping_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_ping,this,::_1,::_2));
```

The complete modified example source looks like:

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp>

#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>

#include <iostream>

/*#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>*/
#include <websocketpp/common/thread.hpp>

typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

using websocketpp::connection_hdl;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

using websocketpp::lib::thread;
using websocketpp::lib::mutex;
using websocketpp::lib::unique_lock;
using websocketpp::lib::condition_variable;

/* on_open insert connection_hdl into channel
 * on_close remove connection_hdl from channel
 * on_message queue send to all channels
 */

enum action_type {
    SUBSCRIBE,
    UNSUBSCRIBE,
    MESSAGE
};

struct action {
    action(action_type t, connection_hdl h) : type(t), hdl(h) {}
    action(action_type t, connection_hdl h, server::message_ptr m)
      : type(t), hdl(h), msg(m) {}

    action_type type;
    websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl;
    server::message_ptr msg;
};

class broadcast_server {
public:
    broadcast_server() {
        // Initialize Asio Transport
        m_server.init_asio();

        // Register handler callbacks
        m_server.set_open_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_open,this,::_1));
        m_server.set_close_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_close,this,::_1));
        m_server.set_message_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_message,this,::_1,::_2));
        m_server.set_ping_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_ping,this,::_1,::_2));
    }

    void run(uint16_t port) {
        // listen on specified port
        m_server.listen(port);

        // Start the server accept loop
        m_server.start_accept();

        // Start the ASIO io_service run loop
        try {
            m_server.run();
        } catch (const std::exception & e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        } catch (websocketpp::lib::error_code e) {
            std::cout << e.message() << std::endl;
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "other exception" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void on_open(connection_hdl hdl) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_action_lock);
        //std::cout << "on_open" << std::endl;
        m_actions.push(action(SUBSCRIBE,hdl));
        lock.unlock();
        m_action_cond.notify_one();
    }

    void on_close(connection_hdl hdl) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_action_lock);
        //std::cout << "on_close" << std::endl;
        m_actions.push(action(UNSUBSCRIBE,hdl));
        lock.unlock();
        m_action_cond.notify_one();
    }

    void on_message(connection_hdl hdl, server::message_ptr msg) {
        // queue message up for sending by processing thread
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_action_lock);
        //std::cout << "on_message" << std::endl;
        m_actions.push(action(MESSAGE,hdl,msg));
        lock.unlock();
        m_action_cond.notify_one();
    }

    bool on_ping(connection_hdl hdl, std::string s)
    {
      /* Do something */
      return true;
    }

    void process_messages() {
        while(1) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_action_lock);

            while(m_actions.empty()) {
                m_action_cond.wait(lock);
            }

            action a = m_actions.front();
            m_actions.pop();

            lock.unlock();

            if (a.type == SUBSCRIBE) {
                unique_lock<mutex> con_lock(m_connection_lock);
                m_connections.insert(a.hdl);
            } else if (a.type == UNSUBSCRIBE) {
                unique_lock<mutex> con_lock(m_connection_lock);
                m_connections.erase(a.hdl);
            } else if (a.type == MESSAGE) {
                unique_lock<mutex> con_lock(m_connection_lock);

                con_list::iterator it;
                for (it = m_connections.begin(); it != m_connections.end(); ++it) {
                    m_server.send(*it,a.msg);
                }
            } else {
                // undefined.
            }
        }
    }
private:
    typedef std::set<connection_hdl,std::owner_less<connection_hdl>> con_list;

    server m_server;
    con_list m_connections;
    std::queue<action> m_actions;

    mutex m_action_lock;
    mutex m_connection_lock;
    condition_variable m_action_cond;
};

int main() {
    try {
    broadcast_server server_instance;

    // Start a thread to run the processing loop
    thread t(bind(&broadcast_server::process_messages,&server_instance));

    // Run the asio loop with the main thread
    server_instance.run(9002);

    t.join();

    } catch (std::exception & e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, it's confirmed: you c++ guys really are geniuses!  Thank you so much!